# how to reduce line spacing in memoir caption

Tags: captions, memoir, line-spacing

For caption in `memoir` document class i use the following settings:

```
\captiondelim{\null\newline}
\captionnamefont{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
\captiontitlefont{\small\sffamily}
\captionstyle[\raggedright]{}
\normalcaptionwidth
\captiontitlefinal{.}
```

I like to reduce line spacing in captions for amount as is scaled used sanserif fonts (`\usepackage[scaled=0.83]{helvet}`), i.e. on 83%. How to do this?

**Edit:**
a MWE as asked Johannes_B:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.83]{helvet}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.82]{luximono}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \captiondelim{\null\newline}
        \captionnamefont{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
        \captiontitlefont{\small\sffamily}
        \captionstyle[\raggedright]{}
        \normalcaptionwidth
        \captiontitlefinal{.}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{figure}[h]\centering
    \fbox{some figure}
    \caption{In long caption text I like to have smaller line spacing as it is now, for example reduced to 83\% of this one. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text of caption}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Out of interest, have you ever been asked to provide a minimal working example? If not, i am the first to ask: Can you prepare a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/)?

Comment: No, because I till to this question always provide a MWE. In this case I hope, that without it the question is enough clear. Anyway, I will prepare it.

Comment: Might be, i haven't checked. I am too lazy right now to build up a test case. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\linespread` expects a multiple of the `\baelineskip`, so here i used .83, or in other word 83 % of the usual baselineskip.

If this is what you are looking for, not sure.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.83]{helvet}
%    \usepackage[scaled=0.82]{luximono}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \captiondelim{\null\newline}
        \captionnamefont{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
    \captiontitlefont{\small\sffamily\linespread{.83}\selectfont}
        \captionstyle[\raggedright]{}
        \normalcaptionwidth
        \captiontitlefinal{.}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{figure}[h]\centering
    \fbox{some figure}
    \caption{\blindtext}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
    \end{document}
```